# How to make a x86 project depend on an AnyCPU project in VSTS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In our VSTS2010 solution, we have a x86-target project that depends on an AnyCPU-target project. When I build the solution, it skips the AnyCPU project, claiming:

```
------ Skipped Build: Project: myproj, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
```

Then it tries to build the x86 project. This fails, because the AnyCPU project DLL is unavailable.

Am I doing something wrong? What additional information would be helpful in understanding the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Build + Configuration Manager.  Tick the Build checkbox.

Comment: Yeah, I realize it's all tied to what's ticked for which build configuration. Can you help me understand what assumptions VS makes about which platform to use? That is, by default it seems to select AnyCPU, but when it encounters my x86 project is switches to x86. What's going on there?

Comment: It is a mess in VS2010, especially when you imported one or more projects from an earlier version.  Who were "AnyCPU" while VS2010 generates "x86", thus producing a nasty mixed bag.  Adding "Mixed" to confound the mess.  The Platform selection doesn't mean anything in managed code, only C++.  Nor does changing it make any difference, the real setting is "Platform target" in the project's Build tab.  And only the EXE project setting matters.  Aggressively cleaning up the mess and removing the junk platforms is a good idea.